# Factor trinomials dividing by the common GCF

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I have a doubt with the following problem I found in a book. You have to simplify a polynomial using the GCF. Now, this is the problem I am not able to grasp:

$$6x^2-19x-7$$

According to the book, the solution is

$$(2x-7)(3x+1)$$

And, in fact, if you multiply those two terms you'll get:

$$6x^2-21x+2x-7=6x^2-19x-7$$

So it is clear that both expressions are equivalent. What I fail to grasp is which method they have followed to come from $6x^2-19x-7$ to $(2x-7)(3x+1)$.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Think about the expanded form of: $(ax+b)(cx+d)$ where any of $a,b,c,d$ can be negative. You should be able to piece together a method for turning a factorable quadratic, such as the given one, into its factored form.

Comment: Are you asking how to factor a [quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation)?  Usual methods: inspection, completing the square, quadratic formula.

Comment: They computed the roots of the quadratic polynomial withe the standard formula. Once you have the roots $x_1, x_2$, you obtain the factorisation $\;ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think they have actually used the AC method, that's the one that makes more sense here.

For a general explanation of such method:

http://www.virtualnerd.com/algebra-1/polynomials-and-factoring/trinomial-factorization/leading-coefficient-not-1/factor-by-a-c-method

So, for this case we have:
$$6x^2-19x-7$$

Hence:
$$a=6, b=-19, c=-7$$

So:
$$ac = -42$$

Then, we calculate the factors of 42 and their sum following the AC method (I tried to use a Latex table but it is a pain in the ass, so sorry about the format.):

$$1\times-42; 1+(-42)=41$$
$$2\times-21; 2+(-21)=-19$$

As $b=-19$ we can stop right there. Our factors are 2 and -21, then $b=2x-21x$

Now, rewriting the trinome with such factors for b, we have then:

$$6x^2+2x-21x-7$$

Now we factor by grouping by pairs:
$$2x(3x+1)-7(3x+1)$$

And now, we have a $(3x+1)$ common factor there, so:
$$(3x+1)(2x-7)$$

Tadaa!

PS. It is worth to add that the book itself ask explicitly to do the factorization dividing by the GCF –hence the question title–, but that's clearly impossible in this case, so it is probably an errata.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I will do it is like this.

First, check if the equation $6x^2−19x−7 = 0 $ has solutions by calculating

$b^2 - 4ac = 19^2 + 4 * 6 * 7 = 529$

Then, we can get the roots from the formula $x = \frac{-b +/- \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} = \frac{19 +/- \sqrt{529}}{2* 6}$  = 3.5/ $-\frac{1}{3}$

So we know the two roots are 3.5 and $-\frac{1}{3}$.

So the equation can be written as $6x^2−19x−7 = (x-3.5)(x+1/3) = (2x−7)(3x+1)$

Comment: So when asked to factor a quadratic polynomial, your approach is to jump straight to the quadratic formula for its roots?  You should then be careful to avoid omitting a constant factor (as you have in the last line here), because knowing the roots will only determine the monic (leading coefficient one) polynomial, which you have equated to the quadratic with leading coefficient $6$.